# PHPExcel: Worksheet not desidered

Tags: php, phpexcel, worksheet

When I create my file with some sheets ("inverter n°"), I found also an empty "Worksheet" sheet. How to eliminate it?

My code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; ++$i) { // to create 4 files
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    for ($n = 1; $n <= 10; ++$n) { // to create 10 sheets for each files

        $objPHPExcel -> createSheet();
        $objPHPExcel -> setActiveSheetIndex($n);
        $objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet() -> setTitle('Inverter '.$n);
        $objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet() -> fromArray($impianti[$i]["inverter".$n]);

    }
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter -> save($output.".xlsx");        
}
```

Comment: there is empty sheet by default with index 0, so you can simply `$objPHPExcel->removeSheetByIndex(0);`

Comment: Thank you, obviously that work!

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel creates a new worksheet when you initialise the object.  Just add in an if statement before you create the sheet :)

Edit: indexing begins at zero so tweaked to reflect this

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; ++$i) { // to create 4 files
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    for ($n = 0; $n < 10; ++$n) { // to create 10 sheets for each files

        if ($n > 0) $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($n);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Inverter '.($n+1));
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($impianti[$i]["inverter".($n+1)]);

    }
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save($output.".xlsx");        
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but, since I put the condition before sheet creating, the script doesn't save files anymore...